# Open taskpane programmatically in desktop outlook

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

Outlook 2013 is using internet explorer as a browser, and that is causing so much problem in our add-in. The add-in is not stable and can't keep fixing bugs caused by internet explorer dialog . I am searching for a way to use taskpane instead of dialog because it is much more stable. However, I didn't find a way to open task pane programmatically, is there any office api or method to open task pane programmatically in outlook 2013 ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to open a task pane programmatically from a web add-in.

You may consider developing a VSTO based add-ins instead where you could use Outlook Form Regions, see [Create Outlook form regions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/creating-outlook-form-regions?view=vs-2019) for more information.